# Symfony2 authenticate user through an API on integration testing

Tags: symfony, authentication, redis, integration-testing, wsse

I would like to authenticate the user through an API (external user provider) running my integration tests.

my config_test.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
    - { resource: parameters_test.yml }

framework:
    test: ~
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: info
```

After the login (SUCCEED) the next step is ask for user information and I got:

```
"Full authentication is required to access this resource."
```

I guess something is happening with the stored session. 
I am using Redis on dev and prod to store sessions. 
Mocking sessions on the test environment because of

```
"Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "/path/to/bin/phpunit" at line 2."
```

Doing it manually is working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

`session.storage.mock_file` uses by default `%kernel.cache_dir%/sessions` for a storing of session's file. Check if this folder is writable for both server user and cli user.

*'Setting up Permissions'* http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup

Another 2 possible reasons of error:

1. `stateless: true` on your firewall in `firewalls` section. The `ContextListener` is not created and Token is not saved to the session. AnonymousToken is assigned to next request.
2. `stateless: true` you also can have `RememberMeToken` instead of `AnonymousToken` if `remember_me` feature enabled. This token is also not full fledged.

**UPDATE**

Ensure that `intercept_redirects` is false in `config_test.yml` as it may break all redirects.

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: false
    intercept_redirects: false
```

Comment: Permissions are completely fine

Comment: What about `stateless`? Are your auth and user information url under the same firewall? What auth type do you use?

Comment: with stateless same problem. yes both are inside the same firewall. my provider type is rest_webservice (custom)

Comment: Remember I'm using Redis to store sessions

Comment: Do you use the same `Client` for consequent requests?`$client= WebTestCase::createClient(); $client->submit(...); $client->request(...);`, etc?

Comment: Do you mean Redis handler? It is used only on dev/prod by `NativeSessionStorage`. `MockFileSessionStorage` writes session into the file.

Comment: I'm using the same client the whole time. I'm using SncRedisBundle to manage sessions on dev and production but I can use that on the test environment aswell but I don't know how to be honest